# What are the benefits of using SafeMath in version >=0.8?

Tags: solidity, safemath

When looking online, I see some answers that there is no use for SafeMath, but I still see some contracts that use it. Is it necessary, or are there any other benefits?

Answer (score 2):

One more use: projects which upgrade from an older version (or a new project which forks an older project). If the old project used SafeMath, it may be just easier to keep using it in the new version as well, instead of modifying all the code.

Answer (score 1):

SafeMath has `try` variants of the operators, which return 0 instead of reverting if an overflow happen. That's about the only benefit of using SafeMath post-0.8 i can think of.